# ASP.NET MVC 5 and Session

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a .NET 4.5+ ASP.NET MVC 5 way of initializing a session variable when a user makes a request the first time only to the application?

Comment: First time only for session, or first time only forever? If session, just check to see if said variable exists in session, if it doesn't then add it. If forever then you'd need to write something to a database to persist this information once a web session times out

Comment: You need to explain what you need in a little more detail.

Comment: First time for session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there something wrong with doing this?

```
if (session["key"] == null)
   session["key"] = value;
```

That seems to accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In function Login add row:

```
   Session["username"] = user;
```

where "username" It can be any name.
Then add in function logout:

```
Session.clear();
```

The Session variables can be used in any Controller and function.